# Резиновое окно игры

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas, математика

Всем привет! Я сейчас пишу игру (использую HTML/CSS/JS, без канваса). Сейчас мне нужно сделать так, чтобы все объекты сцены подстраивались под разные размеры окна. (Надеюсь понятно объяснил).

Задумка у меня была следующая: у меня есть viewport с исходным разрешением (480x800). При запуске игры мы проверяем какие размеры у окна. Относительно них мы пропорционально изменяем размеры viewport. После мы проверяем насколько сильно у нас изменился viewport и делаем отношение предыдущего размера к текущему. Когда этот коэффициент находится, мы умножаем на него все X'ы, Y'и, размеры всех объектов. Но как оказалось этот способ не годится. У кого-нибудь есть идеи?

Вот, этот способ для разных разрешений экрана
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Но как оказалось этот способ не годится" - и здесь темнят. Чем же это он не годится, позвольте узнать?

Comment: Не годится, потому что объект меняет свои размеры не так, как надо. Да и позиционируется он неважно.

Comment: Сдаюсь. Может быть для кого-то "не так, как надо" и "неважно" - информативное описание проблемы.

Comment: @Igor Нужно чтобы игра на всех экранах выглядела одинаково, а не так, чтобы где-то объект слишком большой для данного экрана, где-то слишком маленький.

Comment: Может есть смысл использовать для изометрии движок, пока не поздно? Как плюс это компиляция под ios и android, а также web версия, и сокрашение времени разработки при экономии на велосипедах. Хотя я всегда уважал путь джедаев)

Answer (score 2):

Примените обычный Viewport - [инфо W3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) + для размера окна примените стили как %, но не как статику в пикселях, например style=width:90%. Хорошая идея: установить эти стили прямо в исходном коде вашего окна. Это ускорит загрузку страницы.

Answer (score 0):

адаптивная верстка по относительным величинам в данной реализации изначально не верна, если вы используете только HTML/CSS/JS предлагаю вам задуматься о Bootstrap или сделать все статично в 3 экземплярах под основные разрешения  для маленьких, средних, широкоформатных размеров.
Верно ли я предполагаю что при разном разрешении мониторов у вас настолько разные пропорции ваших "объекты",что в итоге эта разница пропорций делает вашу сцену по критериям внешнего вида как минимум "странной" и как максимум "страшной",если да, то вам необходимо продумать максимальные допустимые размеры для каждого окна и рассмотреть вышеупомянутый Bootstrap(хотя-бы его идею сетки).

Comment: Да, совершенно верно. "Странно" или "Страшно".